# how to detect number of touches on the uiview in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, touch

in my app, when the user touches on the `view` ,i am showing an `UIImageView` there and i drag and

drop the image from another `UIImageView` to that touched `UIImageView`.

But the problem is that, only the recent touched `UIImageView` is activated. i mean ,when i

click 3 times then shows 3 `UIImageViews` but only the last is activated and accept the another

image.

How can i make all touched `UIImageViews` are activated .. Any body help on this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should read Apples documentation on the [responder chain and event handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW1). The key UIView method here is

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

> This method traverses the view hierarchy by sending the
>   pointInside:withEvent: message to each subview to determine which
>   subview should receive a touch event. If pointInside:withEvent:
>   returns YES, then the subview’s hierarchy is traversed; otherwise, its
>   branch of the view hierarchy is ignored. You rarely need to call this
>   method yourself, but you might override it to hide touch events from
>   subviews.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:
Where there is your UIView (Or a view):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;//number of tap
[view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

The selector:

```
-(void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLog(@"Pressed");
}
```

Comment: every time i am getting the count is 1... need to activate all touched uiimageviews .